# VueJS2: Help tracking down "TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined"

Tags: vuejs2

I am using VueJS2 and having the following issue when returning API data from a function:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'P_shortName' of undefined
```

While the UI does render the data successfully after a while, I get annoying console log output above.

In template I have:

```
              <td>
                {{ registerName(country.registerIdentifier_FK) }}
              </td>
```

And the `registerName()` looks like so:

```
methods: {
    async registerName(id) {
      const register = this.registers.find(
        register => id === register.registerIdentifier_PK
      )
      return register.P_shortName
    },
}
```

What can I do to mitigate this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try it.

And I didn't see the need to use async here.

```js
registerName(id) {
  const register = this.registers.find(
    (register) => id === register.registerIdentifier_PK
  );
  return register ? register.P_shortName : null;
}
```

Comment: First, i had a typo in my question code...I don't have 'async' in my actual code, sorry about that. Second...your solution WORKED! Thanks!